# Which is the real color-depth on Windows phone 7 product?

Tags: windows-phone-7, color-depth

According from [Emulator Color Depth](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/24aa46db-bb93-4aed-9520-430de8119216) on Windows Phone 7 forum, I just heard about limitation of Silverlight on Windows Phone 7 that it display only 16-bit color-depth image on Silverlight application just like previous version of Windows Mobile.

Is it true? Anyone can confirm this.

PS.Normally, Silverlight natively support 32-bit color-depth and all modern smart phones also support 24-bit color-depth. I'm not sure what color-depth will be displayed. I have quite bad experience for using HTC Sense in windows mobile 6.5 on my Omnia Pro 2(OLED display with 24-bit color-depth support).

[image: Windows Mobile 6.5 with 16-bit color depth]

**Thanks,**

Answer (score 0):

It's been suggested that the minimum spec for devices is 16 bpp, however I haven't seen the documentation for this despite looking for it. OEMs are free to go beyond this... arguably it will be up to them to put their best foot forward.

There was more background to that discussion you linked in other threads, including the one below. The one you linked doesn't offer a lot of context.

[Emulator gradient quality different from Blend](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/7e7f29f8-edd3-4cbd-8782-1071347397a5)

I think the thing to do at this point will be to look at what's being done on specific devices.

As yet, hardware spec tables I've seen aren't documenting this detail, but it would be good to see.